# dm_db_missing_index_details cutting off fields for included columns

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I am trying to query dm_db_missing_index_details to determine what fields need to be included in an index to optimize performance, but unfortunately the field list is so long it is getting cut off by a length limit on the field.  Is there any way to query this without it cutting off the field list?

Comment: How many fields are include before its cutting it off? the reason i am asking is You do not want wide index because it will slowdown the CRUD operation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1694787/1411000

Comment: May be you can try to export results to file?

Comment: It cuts off at 4000 characters.  I suspect the dynamic management view data type is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your query window and choose Query Options.

Select "Grid" in the left hand pane, and in the right-hand pane, modify the maximum number of characters that can be returned.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears to be a data type issue in the actual dm as it cuts off at 4000 characters.