# What is the difference between composite non clustered index and covering index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, covering-index, composite-index

SQL Server 2005 includes "covering index" feature which allows us to select more than one non key column to be included to the existing non clustered index.

For example, I have the following columns:

```
EmployeeID, DepartmentID, DesignationID, BranchID
```

Here are two scenarios:

- `EmployeeID` is a primary key with
  clustered index and the remaining
  columns (`DepartmentID`, `DesignationID`,
  `BranchID`) are taken as non clustered
  index (composite index).
- `EmployeeID` is a primary key with
  clustered index and `DepartmentID` is
  non clustered index with
  `DesignationID`, `BranchID` are "included
  columns" for non clustered index.

What is the difference between the above two? If both are same what's new to introduce "Covering Index" concept?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that if there are two rows with the same DepartmentID in the first index they will be sorted based on their values of DesignationID and BranchID. In the second case they will not be sorted relative to each other and could appear in any order in the index.

In terms of what this means to your application:

- A query which can use an index on (DepartmentID, DesignationID) can be more efficient with the first query than the second.
- Building the first index may take slightly longer because of the extra sorting required.

Answer (score 0):

Covered index is a nonclustered index with INCLUDE clause