# What does `INCLUDE` do in an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What does `INCLUDE` in an unclustered index?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MyIndex] ON [dbo].[Individual] 
(
    [IndivID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [LastName], [FirstName]) 
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I know the first part is used for the `WHERE` clause, but what do the `INCLUDE` columns do? What's the benefit of having them "added to the leaf level of the nonclustered index"?

*edit* Also if i already have a clustered PK index for `IndivID`, why does Tuning Advisor recommend this index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use the INCLUDE clause when creating an index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

INCLUDE columns include the associated fields WITH the index. They are not used FOR indexing, but they are placed in the leaf node of the B-tree that makes up the index.

In essence: The index is still ON [IndivID] and [IndivID] alone. However, if your query only needs a subset of [IndivID], [LastName] and [FirstName], SQL doesn't need to go back to the table after it's found the [IndivID] it's searching for in the Index.

SEE: [Covering Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index)

EDIT: B-tree assumes MS SQL Server. I'm not positive other implementations use the same data structure

Tuning Advisor (**Speculation**):: A clustered index places the entire data row at the leaf node of the index's B-tree, and this takes up a lot of space. If the Tuning Advisor sees that you're never accessing more than those three fields ([IndivID] + INCLUDEs), it will attempt to save you space (and insert/update time) by downgrading it to a non-clustered index with the only "important" fields present.

Answer (score 5):

`INCLUDE` adds those fields at the leaf-level of the index.  Basically the bt-ree is not sorted by those fields, but once the index finds the row with the indexed field(s) it's looking for, it also has the other fields immediately.

If you use the phone book analogy, the `INCLUDED` fields in the phone book index (which is sorted by `Lastname`, `Firstname`) would be `Phone Number` and `Address` - you can't look up a person by those fields but once you have their name you can find them.

`CLUSTERED` indexes have all fields included already by design, so `INCLUDE` is invalid in a `CLUSTER`.  You also shouldn't bother `INCLUDE`ing the clustered field in a non-clustered index since it is already implicitly there as the row key.

I most often use the `INCLUDE` fields for aggregation.  For instance, if I have an index on `CalendarDate` and `CustomerID` I can include `PaidAmt` and get

`MAX(PAidAmt) Where CustomerId = x AND CalendarDate = 1/1/2011`

At the most basic level they are used to avoid a bookmark or key lookup.

Comment: Well, you CAN still sort by them, (and the query processor doesn't even have to go to the main table pages to do it);  it's just that sinc ethe index is not structured on those columns, the processor can't use the index structure to sort 'on the fly' as it could if the columns were part of the index structure. ...

Comment: @Charles - yes, you are correct.  Apologies for not being clearer.

Comment: @Charles - I clarified that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

That is data that is included as payload in the index. It won't be used to filter, but it can be returned.

If you for example have a query that filters on age and return name:

```
select name
from persons
where age = 42
```

Then you could create an index for the `age` field, with the `name` field included. That way the database could use only the index to run the entire query, and doesn't have to read anything at all from the actual table.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN - [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx):

> INCLUDE (column [ ,... n ] )
>
> Specifies the non-key columns to be added to the leaf level of the nonclustered index.

Meaning, you can add more columns to the unclustered index - if you are returning several fields every time you query on the key column, adding them to the index will improve performance as they are stored with it, aka a [covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index).

Comment: @Raj - No, he is clearly asking what it does. Regardless, I was adding detail regarding benefits.

Comment: I quote *What's the benefit of having them "added to the leaf level of the nonclustered index"?* Now that you added the benefits, I tried to take off the -1, but apparently it has been too much time or something - SO won't let me.

Comment: @Raj - Back at you, I quote: _"but what do the INCLUDE columns do?"_