# Nonclustered index in SQL Server 2008 R2 with includes vs non includes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Running the advisor it suggests I should create an index on `Path`, `Value` and to include `Id`.

```
Path varchar(250)
Value bigint
Id uniqueidentifier
```

1. When using the index in a query, will it be faster having `Id` in the index rather than as an include?
2. Will inserts be slower having `Id` as an include rather than in the index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use the INCLUDE clause when creating an index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1) Depends on query if it looks like

  ```
  select Id 
  from YourTable 
  WHERE Path = x and Value = y and Id =(or>, <, between etc.) z
  ```

i.e. - if query involves exact values (not ranges) of Path and Value - then yes, else - no, will be slower because of more thicker non-leaf rows

- 2) Actually - yes, but it can be negligible, because the sql needs to sort **AND** by Id, but if your Path and Value is versatile enough - the difference will be very tiny. In **IO** there will be a little gain if saving Id in `INCLUDE` section - because no needs to save it on non-leaf pages

As you noticed:

> *Query uses Id, Path and Value. Id and Path in join restriction and
>   Value in where. The Id is furthermore a FK on primary table. With this
>   short info, How would you design the index?*

So, its **better** include all the rows in index, and the best order of columns will depend on structure/indexes of other table in `JOIN`.

The index should look like `(Value, Id, Path)` or `(Value, Path, Id)` - depending on mentioned above.

Comment: Follow up: If I have another case, same design as above but with `Value` being `nvarchar(max)` would it then be: Index(Path) Include(Value, Id)?

Comment: @Daniel - yes, and only like this, varchar(max) cannot be in NON-include part of index

Answer (score 2):

1) If you do operations on the ID which could be addressed by the index (e.g. compare against it), then having it in the index instead of only including it can make the query faster.

2) No, if anything it may be a bit faster and maybe cause less fragmentation in the index as include instead of being part of the index, because the server doesn't have to sort the included columns to put them in the index storage.

Queries run fastest if all the required columns are stored in the index data. Including columns will do just that: add more data to the index without actually indexing it, so that no lookup via PK is required to get the data.

Comment: Query uses Id, Path and Value. Id and Path in join restriction and Value in where. The Id is furthermore a FK on primary table. With this short info, How would you design the index?

Comment: If `Id` is used in the join predicate, then I'd probably add it to the index no matter what the advisor tells me. Assuming that you're running your query against test data it may well be the the query analyzer will choose a different execution plan with different data and therefore use the `Id` in the index as well.

Comment: Then better create index like (Value, Id, Path) ?

Comment: @OlegDok, no, `(Value, Path, Id)`, assuming that `Id` is unique it should be at the last position of the index (and maybe include other columns if required, but adding them is pointless if the index is known to be unique at that point).