# How can i avoid an extra inner join to optimize this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

Is there any way where I can avoid the inner join to get the customer firstname, and lastname from customer table and how can i optimize the execution plan?

```
SELECT c1.firstname, c1.lastname, t.*
FROM customer c1
INNER JOIN
    (select c.Customerid ,count(si.CustomerID) as 'No Of Orders'
    from Customer c
    LEFT OUTER join SalesInvoice si ON si.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    GROUP by c.CustomerID) as t
ON c1.CustomerID = t.Customerid
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think INNER JOIN is a bad thing? This query is better then grouping by firstname, lastname. COUNT() OVER() should be roughly as good as your one. I'd do Customer LEFT JOIN (select CustomerID, count(*) cnt from SalesInvoice GROUP BY CustomerID) if your purpose is brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 ways to do it. 
One way is to include all non-aggregate columns into the group by list as below:

```
SELECT
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname,
    c.CustomerId,
    count(si.CustomerID) as 'No Of Orders'
FROM
    customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SalesInvoice si ON si.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerID,
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname
```

Another way to do it, would be to use an aggregate function (min or max should do) in the select list:

```
SELECT
    MIN(c.firstname) as firstname,
    MIN(c.lastname) as lastname,
    c.CustomerId,
    count(si.CustomerID) as 'No Of Orders'
FROM
    customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SalesInvoice si ON si.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerID
```

I think the first query may be better in performance. To improve overall performance you will need to create an included or covering index.

You can have a look at the following links to give you an idea on included indexes:

1. [Why use the INCLUDE clause when creating an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index)
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this option with [OVER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause

```
SELECT c1.Customerid, c1.firstname, c1.lastname, 
       COUNT(si.CustomerID) OVER(PARTITION BY c1.CustomerID) AS 'No Of Orders'
FROM customer c1 LEFT JOIN SalesInvoice si ON si.CustomerID = c1.CustomerID
```

For improving performance you need this index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Customerid_Customer ON Customer(Customerid) INCLUDE(firstname, lastname)
```

Comment: This will repeat the customerid, firstname

Comment: @Vishwanath Dalvi  In example OP the customerid, firstname repeat too;)

Answer (score 0):

Try that one:

```
SELECT
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname,
    c.CustomerId,
    count(si.CustomerID) as 'No Of Orders'
FROM
    customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SalesInvoice si ON si.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerID,
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname
```