# Indexes with columns included

Tags: sql-server

I noticed in my database that I have a lot of indexes in a table that only differ in the included columns.

For example for table A I have this:

```
INDEX ON A(COLUMN_A) INCLUDE (COLUMN_B)
INDEX ON A(COLUMN_A) INCLUDE (COLUMN_C)
INDEX ON A(COLUMN_A) INCLUDE (COLUMN_D)
```

It seems to me it would be more efficient (for inserts/updates/deletes) to just have this:

```
INDEX ON A(COLUMN_A) INCLUDE (COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D)
```

Would there be any reason not to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, they should be combined into one. The non-key columns that are `INCLUDE`-ed are just stored in the leaf nodes of the index so they can be read. Unlike key columns they don't form part of the hierarchy of the index so the order isn't important. Having fewer indexes is a good thing if the indexes aren't adding anything useful, as in this case with your redundant indexes.

See also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308012/8479

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this is a read optimization, not write. If there are multiple queries that use the same key column (`COLUMN_A`), but using a different "data" column (`COLUMN_B/C/D`), using this kind of index saves some I/O (no need to load unnecessary data from the table, you already have it along with the index). Including all the data columns in one index would take less space overall (no need to have the key column saved three timse), but each of the indices in your case is smaller than one "combined" index.

Hopefully, the indices were created this way for a reason, based on performance profiling and real performance issues. This is where documentation with motivation comes in very handy - why were the indices created this way? Was it sloppiness? Little understanding of the way indices work? Automatic optimization based on query plan analysis? Unless you know that, it might be a bad idea to tweak this kind of thing, especially if you don't actually have a performance problem.