# Merging SQL Server indexes on same key but different INCLUDE columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

Using Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzIndex to highlight missing indexes (*Indexaphobia: High value missing index*) from several SQL Server databases with a common layout but different end-users.

Some of the suggestions involve indexes with `INCLUDE(...)` and I'm not sure if I can combine several of these potential indexes - as an example say I have several sets of people (`tblPeople`) being queried in slightly different ways which has produced the following suggestions;

```
CREATE INDEX [ix_tblPeople_ZipCode] ON [dbo].[tblPeople] ([ZipCode]);

CREATE INDEX [ix_tblPeople_ZipCode_include_A] ON [dbo].[tblPeople] ([ZipCode]) INCLUDE ([FirstName]);

CREATE INDEX [ix_tblPeople_ZipCode_include_B] ON [dbo].[tblPeople] ([ZipCode]) INCLUDE ([LastName]);

CREATE INDEX [ix_tblPeople_ZipCode_include_C] ON [dbo].[tblPeople] ([ZipCode]) INCLUDE ([BusinessName]);
```

Would combining these into a single index which `INCLUDE`'d all those columns be useful for all three scenarios or is there a better approach?

```
CREATE INDEX [ix_tblPeople_ZipCode_include] ON [dbo].[tblPeople] ([ZipCode]) INCLUDE ([BusinessName], [LastName], [FirstName]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would probably be a good idea - fewer indexes means fewer maintenance overhead when you insert, update or delete rows.

And since those columns are merely *included* at the leaf-level, there's no negative impact on the navigation structure of the index, either.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If your queries have a where clause like

```
where  firstname  like 'John'
and    lastname   like 'Smith'
and    businesName like 'StackOverflow'
and    zipCode    like '12345'
```

Then the included columns will not be used - only the indexed column (zipCode) will be used to filter results.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index).