# Difference in index declaration between specifying columns in ON clause and in INCLUDE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

Just wondering about indexes. It's a quite new concept for me and I can't see the difference between declaring columns in ON clause and in INCLUDE clause. Examples below should explain the matter:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_client_info1
ON dbo.client(name, age, city)
WHERE name = 'A%';

CREATE INDEX ix_client_info2
ON dbo.client(name)
INCLUDE(age, city)
WHERE name = 'A%';
```

How these two indexes differ in behaviour? Which to use in which situations?

Comment: For some additional reading see [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `included` columns are not ordered in the index; they don’t belong to the index tree, they are just added to the leafs.

So this basically means two things:

- the index is a bit smaller, and there is less overhead to maintain it
- the index will not help if included columns are used for filtering (like in the `where` clause, `on` clause of a join, or in the `group by` clause) or for sorting (like in the `order by` clause); it is only useful when the columns are used solely in the `select` clause so this comes handy when you want a *covering* index)

There are not many cases when included columns are useful, unless you are doing advanced optimization. In general, you want regular columns keys.

Comment: Thanks. For future seekers, here more about the topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index