# Why SQL query takes too long time to execute when joining two tables and one table has lot of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```sql
SELECT object_oid,
       parent_oid,
       object_type,
       filetype,
       token
FROM TemporaryFiles
WHERE token NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                           TemporaryFiles.token
                    FROM TemporaryFiles
                         INNER JOIN Tokens ON TemporaryFiles.token = Tokens.token);
```

**TemporaryFiles** Table - Table has around  ~5,000 Rows

```
----------------------------------------------------
Column Name     DataType
OBJECT_OID      int 
PARENT_OID      int 
OBJECT_TYPE     varchar(100)    
FileType        varchar(255)    
Token           varchar(255)    
DBKEY           int    ------------------------Primary Key
```

This table has one clustered index on Primary Key DBKey

**Tokens** Table  - Table has around  ~900,000 Rows

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Column Name     DataType
OBJECT_OID      int
PARENT_OID      int
OBJECT_TYPE     nvarchar(64)
CHILD_TYPE      nvarchar(64)
FileType        nvarchar(32)
Token           nvarchar(255)
CreationTime    datetime
Contextual      bit
DBKEY           int      ------------------------Primary Key
```

There is one clustered index on Primary Key on DBKey
And one non clustered index on OBJECT_OID ,OBJECT_TYPE,Contextual,

I tried to create one more **non clustered index on Token**  for both tables. Still the query is taking infinite time to execute.

Even i tried to change "Not in" to "NOT EXIST" statement. But still issue i see.

Comment: FYI a `DISTINCT` with a `NOT IN` is overly going to cause unneeded overhead.

Comment: you are joining and filtering on Token but you don't have an index on that column.  Then it 's normal that it will take time.

Comment: Your current Subquery can be replaced by `NOT IN (SELECT  TemporaryFiles.token  FROM TemporaryFiles)` (if both tokens are NOT NULL), but the optimizer should be smart enough to create the same plan in both cases.

Comment: One more thing is this same query works fine in MSSql -2008 R2, But in MSSql 2012 it's taking more time.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you try the following.  Your DISTINCT is really not necessary and just adding a lot of extra work:

```
SELECT object_oid,
       parent_oid,
       object_type,
       filetype,
       token
FROM TemporaryFiles
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tokens AS T WHERE T.Token = TemporaryFiles.Token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using left join to get all temp files without tokens

```
    SELECT object_oid,
       parent_oid,
       object_type,
       filetype,
       token
FROM TemporaryFiles a
     left join Tokens ON TemporaryFiles.token = Tokens.token
where Tokens.token is null
```

Index wise: maybe test using nonclusted on token and the includes for the columns used in the select (why see explanation here)
[Indexing/Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index)