# How can I share some WHERE clauses but still add unique ones for multiple sums?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, case

I have a single table with some simple number i'd like to sum across different date ranges. Example:

```
date     | cost | storeId | stateId |
-------------------------------------
1/1/2021 | 100  | 1       |  1      |
1/1/2020 | 30   | 2       |  2      |
```

I would like to sum the costs across different timespans, so sum of the costs of records within 1 month of now, 2 months of now, etc. I also have several conditions on which to count that require JOINs. This led me to creating a massive query that reuses the same joins and where clause (except the date range) and UNIONs:

```
SELECT SUM(cost)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.storeId
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.stateId
WHERE t1.date > '1monthAgo' t2.otherId = 1 AND t2.anotherId = 2 AND t3.someId = 1
UNION
SELECT SUM(cost)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.storeId
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.stateId
WHERE t1.date > '2monthsAgo' t2.otherId = 1 AND t2.anotherId = 2 AND t3.someId = 1
UNION
SELECT SUM(cost)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.storeId
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.stateId
WHERE t1.date > '3monthsAgo' t2.otherId = 1 AND t2.anotherId = 2 AND t3.someId = 1
```

In my real query, these joins and where clauses are much more complicated and make this query not just a mess, but very slow (~4 seconds). I tried re-writing this with CASE statements, and now have:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE t1.date > '1monthAgo' THEN t1.cost ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE t1.date > '2monthsAgo' THEN t1.cost ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE t1.date > '3monthsAgo' THEN t1.cost ELSE 0 END),
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.storeId
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.stateId
WHERE t2.otherId = 1 AND t2.anotherId = 2 AND t3.someId = 1
```

This presents the data slightly differently (all in one row) but it runs much faster (1 second) and doesn't duplicate the JOINs and WHERE clauses. However my real query has 4 different sums across 6 different date ranges, so there are 24 CASE statements and I do not think this is the right way to do this.

Is it possible to have a single query that would share the JOINs and WHERE clauses but allow me to query across different date ranges to gather sums?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. Based on your description using case expressions is the best way to go. There might be ways to further simplify things, but could only suggest after seeing the actual query.

Comment: Is your date indexed? Have you tried to include the cost column directly in the date index? It should be almost instant, even with the union version. Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307990/why-use-the-include-clause-when-creating-an-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One option is to group by `EOMONTH` which gives you a single date per month, then you have each month in a separate row:**

```sql
SELECT 
  MonthEnding = EOMONTH(t1.date),
  TotalCost   = SUM(t1.cost)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.storeId
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.stateId
WHERE t2.otherId = 1 AND t2.anotherId = 2 AND t3.someId = 1
GROUP BY EOMONTH(t1.date);
```

If these "months" are actually not aligned with calendar months then you can join on a `VALUES` table with month numbers

```sql
SELECT 
  v.MonthsAgo,
  TotalCost   = SUM(t1.cost)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.storeId
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.stateId
JOIN (VALUES
  (CAST('20210521' AS date), CAST('20210621' AS date), 1),
  (CAST('20210421' AS date), CAST('20210521' AS date), 2),
  (CAST('20210321' AS date), CAST('20210421' AS date), 3)
) v(StartDate, EndDate, MonthsAgo)
  ON t1.date >= v.StartDate AND t1.date < v.EndDate
WHERE t2.otherId = 1 AND t2.anotherId = 2 AND t3.someId = 1
GROUP BY v.MonthsAgo;
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Runs in about 2 seconds, though looking at the query execution plan i'm missing some indexes on joined tables so that should speed it up a bit